# How to disable code optimization during build process for a certain aspect and for certain lines to run my code correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin

My code actually looks like this:

```
setTheme()
setContentView()
view.setxyz(verytimeintensivefunction())
```

I want to execute the time intensive function before setTheme() to show my splash screen during execution. So i made this:

```
var x = verytimeintensivefunction()
setTheme()
setContentView()
view.setxyz(x)
```

Than I have debugged the app and set a breakpoint on setContentView() to check in the profiler when the task has finished executing. And the execution was done after setContentView(). So i think that during the build process the code will be simplified. So how can I execute the function when the splash screen is showing?

Comment: Are you saying you want to run your function before ``setTheme``, and the task needs to complete before the next lines get executed? It should already happen that way - if it moves on to ``setTheme`` and ``setContentView`` before the task is finished, then your task is running async and not blocking the main thread - like you're calling a network library that runs off the main thread (which is good, because blocking the main thread is very bad). I feel like you probably want to make your activity show the splash screen, and update the display once you get your data through a callback

Answer (score 0):

Use Coroutines and try once.

```
GlobalScope.launh(Dispathers.Main){
var x = verytimeintensivefunction()
setTheme()
setContentView()
view.setxyz(x)
}
```

This basically executes the code sequentially in the Main thread. And also if it didnt work please explain in detail.

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work. It is all like before, beside that i have the same layout problems that i had when i executed setTheme() after setContentView(). setTheme() changes the splash screen theme to my AppTheme, and my verytimeintensivefunction() is downloading some websites and saving some informations out of it.